# cron expression for every 30 seconds in quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I am using Quartz Scheduler to run my jobs. I want to run my job every thirty seconds. What will be my cron expression for that?

For every one minute, I am using below cron expression:

```
<cron-expression>0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>
```

What it will be for every thirty seconds?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The first element represents the seconds; to run at second 0 and 30 use the following:

```
<cron-expression>0/30 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *</cron-expression>
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. One more thing what will be the cron expression to run every 15 minutes but for the first time it should run immediately? And then afterwards every 15 minutes? Does this looks right `0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *`?

Comment: That is the correct cron expression for every 15 minutes.  Cron is a rigid structure, and doesn't conform well what you are asking (now, now+15min, etc).  That cron will run at minute, 0, 15, 30, 45 ..

Comment: Maybe you need Triggers, not cron

Comment: If you're using  ```spring [spring-boot]``` make sure to omit last  * , otherwise it will throw an error saying can't accept fields other than six.

Answer (score 12):

I hope this answer will help you. Please define the cron expression the below

```
 0/30 * * * * ? *
```

And then you go this website and test [Cron Expression Generator & Explainer - Quartz](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html).

Answer (score 11):

The same effect we can reach (Quartz Spring) using simpler construction:

```
0/30 * * * * ? *
```

The last asterisk we can omit.

```
0/30 * * * * ?
```

[Quartz scheduler cron trigger documentation 2.x](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring framework, make use of `@PostConstruct` annotation and then `@Scheduled(cron=0 0/15 * 1/1 * ?)` to trigger now, now+15min and so on.